# Regex something or nothing

Tags: regex

i have this regex:

```
/\<p(.+?|)>(.+?)<\/p\>/ims
```

which matches all the `<p>` inside an .html doc. However sometimes the `<p>` has attributes (like class, style, id etc.. ) and sometimes it doesn't.

The problem with this regex is if the `<p>` has no attributes it matches the closing tag of the.

here is an example:

https://regex101.com/r/jX5kS3/1

Comment: Please see [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/476) [**Regex is not the way to parse HTML.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476)

Comment: Are you sure????????// https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/10

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jX5kS3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
<p(.*?)>(.+?)<\/p\>
```

https://regex101.com/r/pR0iB2/1